# How to create a matrix with 20 columns in latex

Tags: matrices, columns

The code below works,  but when I add 10 more columns, it does not. So, how can I add ten more columns to the matrix below?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

One simple way is to use the `array` environment together the expansible brackets `\left[` and `\right]` (note the use of `{*{20}c}` as suggested by @cmhughes):

```
\left[
\begin{array}{*{20}c}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{array}
\right]
```

The problem is the difference on the spacing for the brackets.

---

From the `texdoc amsmath` documentation:

> The maximum number of columns in a matrix is determined by the counter `MaxMatrixCols` (normal value = 10), which you can change if necessary using
>   `\setcounter` or `\addtocounter` commands.

So, you can just use

```
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: @Günal, there is a global solution. Before to replace all your matrices, consider reading the updated answer.

Comment: +1 you shouldn't need to write `{ccccccccccccc}` and can use `{*{20}c}
`

Comment: “The problem is the difference on the spacing for the brackets.” → Use `\begin{array}{@{}<columns>@{}}` instead, i.e. `\begin{array}{@{}*{20}c@{}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `bmatrix`, you could use a `+bmatrix` from the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{+bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{+bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```