# Error in matrix form?

Tags: matrices

I am writing this matrix in my report:

```
  \begin{align}
  \mathbf{x}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}^\mathrm{T},
  \end{align}
```

I found errors `pdfLatex> ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr`

Comment: This is very similar in nature to [How to create a matrix with 20 columns in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95162/5764). The solution is to increase the maximum number of columns to suit your needs (via the counter `MaxMatrixCols`).

Comment: @Werner Your link makes my answer look a little silly, even though my route was RTFM:) Probably should be marked as a duplicate and I shold delete my answer.

Comment: @Andrew: Although the question is a duplicate, it does not mean that your answer is silly or wrong. There is no need of deleting it really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `amsldoc` manual:

```
The maximum number of columns in a matrix is determined by the counter 
MaxMatrixCols (normal value = 10), which you can change if necessary 
using LATEX’s \setcounter or \addtocounter commands.
```

So you need:

```
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{x}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}^\mathrm{T},
\end{align}
```

(You seem to have only 16 columns, but gave you an extra 4 just in case:)