# How to stop row array from overflowing to next line

Tags: equations, formatting, margins

I am new to TeX, and I love it, but one thing drives me crazy. For a lot of courses, I need to add state row vectors that are bigger than 6 columns. However every time I try to add a row vector using the `\bmatrix` object the last columns get put on the next line. Is there a way to prohibit this behaviour maybe by setting the equation for vertical overflow margins or do you have any tips on how to best input such a large column state matrix?

## **Example:**

#### Input:

```
\begin{equation}
 x0 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} & y_1 & phi_1 & x_2 & y_2 & phi_2 & \dot{x_1} & \dot{y_1} & \dot{phi_1} & \dot{x_2} & \dot{y_2} & \dot{phi_2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

#### Output

[image]

#### Expected behaviour:

I wanted one big column array which does not overflow until the side margins are reached.

### **Used packages:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please don't use screenshots for code. Are those made with a standard `bmatrix`? You should get an error then, as by default `matrix` and the like has a max of ten columns, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95162/how-to-create-a-matrix-with-20-columns-in-latex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments @TorbjørnT. I uploaded the formatting and keep it in mind for the next time. The link you send is exactly the one I was looking for. I'm ashamed that I couldn't find it myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dexteritas Thanks a lot for the welcome message and the source to the working example I will keep it in mind next time!