# Present list of vectors nicely aligned

Tags: align, amsmath

I'm writing a file where I have to present 14 eigenvectors of (column) length 14 in a nice way. So far I have tried with with `align*` environment, but I'm not getting the desired results. Basically I want to have one row of 7 vectors side by side and a second row of another 7 vectors (or all in one row if space allows), but I don't now how to align them entry by entry so that the vertical lenghts line up.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
            \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},
        &   \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0  \end{pmatrix}, 
        &   \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix},
        &   \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix},
        &   \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix},
        &   \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix},
        &   \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix},
        &   \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix} 
        % \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}  \\
        % \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}  
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add the documentclass and the used packages to your [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Sry, I've edited my post accordingly

Comment: How about [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/nBM1uifM) option ([output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NovtA.png))?

Comment: @Werner I've tried this as a possible alternative, but in 12pt the input doesn't fit the page. Is there a command to make a matrix smaller relative to general document?

Comment: @cQQkie: I'd suggest adding `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{.8\arraycolsep}` (see [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/cHuqNyuH)) to reduce the column separation by (say) 20%. You can adjust the `.8` (20%) to suit your needs. Let me know.

Comment: @Werner Yes, thank you. This works quite well and suits my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different approach that sets the entire collection of vectors in a matrix. You can adjust the column separation (`\arraycolsep`) to suit your needs, depending on the available space in the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95162/5764

\begin{document}

\[
  \bm{\epsilon} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \bm{\epsilon}_1^T \\
      \\
      \vdots \\
      \\
      \bm{\epsilon}_{14}^T
    \end{bmatrix} =
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{.8\arraycolsep}% Reduce array column separation by 20%
    \begin{bmatrix}
       1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 \\ %  1
       0 &  s &  0 & -s &  s & -s &  0 &  1 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\ %  2
       0 &  s &  0 & -s &  s & -s &  0 &  1 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\ %  3
       0 & -s &  1 &  s &  0 &  0 & -s &  1 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 & -1 \\ %  4
      -1 &  s &  1 &  s &  0 &  0 & -s & -1 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 & -1 \\ %  5
       1 &  s &  1 &  s &  0 &  0 & -s & -1 &  0 & -1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 \\ %  6
       1 &  s &  1 & -s &  0 &  1 &  s & -1 &  0 & -1 & -1 &  0 & -1 &  0 \\ %  7
       1 &  s &  1 &  s &  0 &  0 & -s & -1 &  0 & -1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 \\ %  8
       1 &  s &  1 &  s &  0 &  0 & -s & -1 &  0 & -1 &  1 & -1 &  0 &  1 \\ %  9
       1 &  s &  1 &  s &  0 &  0 & -s & -1 &  0 & -1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 \\ % 10
       1 &  s &  1 &  s &  0 &  0 & -s & -1 &  0 & -1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 \\ % 11
       1 &  s &  1 &  s &  0 &  0 & -s & -1 &  0 & -1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 \\ % 12
       1 &  s &  1 &  s &  0 &  0 & -s & -1 &  0 & -1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 \\ % 13
       1 &  s &  1 &  s &  0 &  0 & -s & -1 &  0 & -1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1    % 14      
   \end{bmatrix}
\]
where $s = 1/\sqrt{2}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 though personally I'd prefer `{bmatrix*}[r]` from `mathtools`.

Comment: @campa: Yaaass!