# How to write a 20x20 matrix in LaTex

Tags: matrices

I want to write a matrix having 20x20 dimension. But in latex (using the package amsmath) number of columns is limited to 10.
Please solve my problem.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95162/how-to-create-a-matrix-with-20-columns-in-latex

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3519/how-to-use-more-than-10-tab-stops-in-bmatrix-or-other-amsmath-matrix-environment

Answer (score 0):

By default `bmatrix` takes 10 columns. So you have to use

```
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
```

in the preamble to increase it to 20 (say)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs,latexsym,paralist}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0  & 0  & 1 & -1 & 1  & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0  & -1 & 0  & 1 & -1 & 0  & 1  & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0  & 0  & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0  & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is reason for loading all those packages besides `amsmath`?

Comment: please remove the uneeded pack by compiling and commenting out one by one

Comment: My point is that when answering to a new user one should better restrict the code to the _necessary_ packages. Here only `amsmath` is relevant. `amssymb` would already load `amsfonts`; `amsthm`, `mathrsfs` and `paralist` are irrelevant; `latexsym` is outdated.