# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr (scaling the equation)

Tags: equations, size

I want to write that equation in latex but I get error at title.

'''

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{w}^{(1)} & y_{w}^{(1)} & z_{w}^{(1)} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -u_{1}x_{w}^{(1)} & -u_{1}y_{w}^{(1)} & -u_{1}z_{w}^{(1)} & -u_{1} \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{w}^{(1)} & y_{w}^{(1)} & z_{w}^{(1)} & 1 & -v_{1}x_{w}^{(1)} & -v_{1}y_{w}^{(1)} & -v_{1}z_{w}^{(1)} & -v_{1} \\ 
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    x_{w}^{(i)} & y_{w}^{(i)} & z_{w}^{(i)} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -u_{i}x_{w}^{(i)} & -u_{i}y_{w}^{(i)} & -u_{i}z_{w}^{(i)} & -u_{i} \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{w}^{(i)} & y_{w}^{(i)} & z_{w}^{(i)} & 1 & -v_{i}x_{w}^{(i)} & -v_{i}y_{w}^{(i)} & -v_{i}z_{w}^{(i)} & -v_{i} \\ 
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    x_{w}^{(n)} & y_{w}^{(n)} & z_{w}^{(n)} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -u_{n}x_{w}^{(n)} & -u_{n}y_{w}^{(n)} & -u_{n}z_{w}^{(n)} & -u_{n} \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{w}^{(n)} & y_{w}^{(n)} & z_{w}^{(n)} & 1 & -v_{n}x_{w}^{(n)} & -v_{n}y_{w}^{(n)} & -v_{n}z_{w}^{(n)} & -v_{n} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    p_{11} \\ p_{12} \\ p_{13} \\ p_{14} \\ p_{21} \\ p_{22} \\ p_{23} \\ p_{24} \\ p_{31} \\ p_{32} \\ p_{33} \\ p_{34}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Can you help me to edit it?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}` as discussed here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68628959

Comment: Relevant answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95163/3929,

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comments.